# Not able to connect to Syabse database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

Hi I am getting problem of not connecting to sybase database using jdbc. I have also put jconn.jar in dependency of intellij 12.1.

I am getting the following excpetion

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sybase:some.com:8000/DBAQ02
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>       at gbconnect.DBConnectPOC.main(DBConnectPOC.java:81)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Please see the following code . Please guide I am really got mad. Thanks in advance.

```
try
            {
                Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Driver class '" + driverClassName + "' is not valid.", e);
            }

        }

        //jdbc:jtds:sybase://some.com:8000/DBAQ02
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println(driverClassName + "://" + url);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sybase:some.com:8000/DBAQ02","sa","abc");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(SQL_CREATE);
            System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
        }
```

Comment: what driver do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know m way too late but came across this question just now.
So, here are some things:
Did you try:
1)jconn4.jar

2)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");

3)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:some.com:8000?ServiceName=DBAQ02", "sa", "abc");

4)Are you sure the url is: some.com?

5)Instead of using some.com, why don't you put the actual IP address?

6)Are you sure 8000 is the port? Check it once.

Link source that helped:
http://fm4dd.com/database/howto-install-Sybase-jdbc.htm

Comment: If you are suggesting than it should be good to leave comment instead of give as an answer. Thank you

Comment: I had tried to click comment, but it says: reputation 50 is needed to comment, which I don't have as I have just started. So I cannot leave comment.

Comment: Yes there are some rules you can say. As i read your answer you are just suggesting do this or this. So its would be good if you can ask some of these points from Op to clarify in comments by doing this the question would be clear to you and you can write a very good and specific answer for that problem. you can also go through this link [When to answer and when to comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265972/when-to-answer-and-when-to-comment) [and this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=when+to+comment+and+when+to+answer+)

Comment: I understand the problem, but I'm giving different things that could have gone wrong and can be tried. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Please check your connection URL.

It should be `jdbc:sybase:Tds:some.com:8000` for the driver you are loading.

Comment: I have also tried jdbc:sybase:Tds:DBAQ02-some.com:8000/DBAQ02 but same exception no suitable driver found for jdbc:sybase:Tds:DBAQ02-some.com:8000/DBAQ02